# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen other answers but it didn't work. I use Python 3.6.1 and `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` keeps stopping me.

I am trying to import python, I know I know. I am a complete newbie. Though if anyone knows how to get python on a 32 bit windows seven please tell me. Even if it doesn't use pip.

My code:

```
import pip
pip ("C:/Users/Afolabi/Downloads/pygame-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl")
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to install a package, try `pip install pygame` **on the command line**. If not, what  *are* you trying to do?

Comment: if you're trying to install the wheel from that path, open a console / terminal and type `pip install <path_to_whl>`

Comment: Why the down votes? Its perfectly legal to import pip and call its main. Not normal, but doable.

Comment: Well sorry for asking what most of you guys think is a bad question I am just a newbie and methods of installing pygame haven't been working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pip` is usually called from the command line like

```
pip install C:\Users\Afolabi\Downloads\pygame-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
```

But all pip does is to import the `pip` module and call its `main` and you can do that too

```
import pip
pip.main("C:/Users/Afolabi/Downloads/pygame-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl")
```

Answer (score 0):

pip is a module

pip ("C:/Users/Afolabi/Downloads/pygame-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl") is a function call

I guess @jonrsharpe is right but you could try pip.pip, or from pip import pip